# Partial View action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, action, partial-views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET MVC 3 controller action for partial view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274831/asp-net-mvc-3-controller-action-for-partial-view)

I have a page that contains a partial view.

This partial view has a custom model and I thought about replacing it with a regular action+view calling `Html.RenderAction` so I can control its model retrieval, styles and scripts separately.

The problem is I want to exclude the outer layout page from that view.
Is it possible? Is this efficient? Any better alternatives?

Comment: Flagging your own question as duplicate... that's unexpected )

Comment: I wasn't sure if this question should be deleted, so I decided to give the community a hint and let them decide :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7276944/75500).

In short, instead of returning `View` in that action, `PartialView` should be returned.